# JSON parse error on object property value

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am new to JSON and I think JSON.parse get the value of key you want to find or at least that what I understood from it's definition. But I am getting a error which I cannot understand.

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Unexpected end of JSON input ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

My end result is to convert the value of the key using `atob` for each result. My code is as following

```
    loadUserInfo() {
        this.getUsers()
            .then((result) => {
                for (const dx of result){
                    const signs = dx.signature;
                    console.log(JSON.parse(signs));
                }
                   // const conv = atob(decode64);
                   // const myImg = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${conv}`;
                    //console.log(myImg);

    };
}
```

If I don't use JSON.parse, my code return correct converted `atob` but in object notation

Comment: Post a sample of your result variable.

Comment: You can't parse something that is already an object. do you mean stringify?

Comment: @Pavlo I have no idea about stringfy or parse.

Comment: @Nofel if you have no idea about `parse`, why are you using it?

Comment: @jeff result of which stage? `result`?

Comment: @Nofel Are you sure you know what you are doing and what you need to achieve?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzcześniak I m trying to get `atob` of the object value.

Comment: @Nofel Please rewrite your question and specify: what you need to do, what is your input, what is your presumed output and what have you tried (and why it failed).

Comment: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${conv}`;`   this data url is expecting base64 data, but yet you are using `atob`,  instead of `btoa`

Comment: @Keith isn't atob is a decode, that is what I am trying to do, as I stored the image using btoa in db as blob

Comment: Indeed `atob` is the decode, but in your instance if your appending to a data url, your certainly don't want it to be the decoded there, it's expecting base64, and you have now made it into binary..

Answer (score 0):

JSON is object notation, used for serializing data.

`JSON.parse` is function that parses valid JSON string and outputs JavaScript object. There is opposite function - `JSON.stringify` - that serializes JavaScript object into valid JSON string.

Comment: This works! but how do I convert that string into atob and make it display a image? what was I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nofel `atob` encodes something into base64. `btoa` decodes base64 string. Are you sure which one you need to use, if any?

Comment: The image is a blob, which was converted using `btoa` so I assume If I need to display the image back it is `atob`? I am new to JS

Comment: @Nofel No, if your data is in base64, just pass it to `data:image/jpeg;base64,{{data}}`.

Comment: I get the [following](https://jsfiddle.net/11efw3pm/) output,I don't think it is valid?

Comment: @Nofel It is impossible to reason, you give non-complete samples and some random output. I do not own a crystal ball.

Answer (score 0):

```
loadUserInfo() {
    this.getUsers()
        .then((result) => {
            for (const dx of result){
                const signs = dx.signature;
                console.log(signs); //Show this
                console.log(JSON.parse(signs));
            }
        }).catch((reason) => { 
            console.log(reason); //show this too
        });
    }
}
```

If you give these things, then we can see where it goes wrong

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`